# How to pull current and past month data SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to list the trade dates, and stock closing prices for the each month of the year (which I will refer to as the 'current' month) and the stock closing price for the month preceding the 'current' month.

The `StockData` table I am using has has columns for date, Stock high, low, opening, closing, and volume for each trade date and ticker symbol.

Initially, I used `AVG`:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(TradeDate) AS Year, 
    MONTH(TradeDate) AS Month, 
    TickerSymbol, 
    AVG(ST_Close) AS CurrentClose,
    LAG (AVG(ST_Close), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY TickerSymbol, YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), TickerSymbol) AS PreviousMonthClose,
FROM 
    StockData
WHERE
    TradeDate >= '2000-01-01' AND ST_Close IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), TickerSymbol
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), TickerSymbol;
```

But instead of using the average, I'd like to pull the stock closing price from the last day of each month, and the previous last day of the last month (for April 2010, I want to show the Stock Closing price on April 30th, 2010 and March 31st, 2010)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server that you are using.

Comment: Will a record always exist on these days? If not I guess you want to get the prior one. Your first challenge is to write a SQL statement that contians an expression that gives you these dates. Hint you use a combination of `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD` and some other bits. There will be many examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one method, which assumes the previous close value you need is from the date the stock last traded during the previous month.

```
WITH
    daily_close AS (
        SELECT  
            TradeDate
          , TickerSymbol
          , ST_Close
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TickerSymbol, EOMONTH(TradeDate) ORDER BY TradeDate DESC) AS day_num
        FROM    dbo.StockData
        WHERE   TradeDate >= '2012-01-01'
                AND ST_Close IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT
        YEAR(curr.TradeDate) AS Year
      , MONTH(curr.TradeDate) AS Month
      , curr.TickerSymbol
      , curr.ST_Close AS CurrentMonthClose
      , prev.ST_Close AS PriorMonthClose
FROM daily_close AS curr
LEFT JOIN daily_close AS prev ON
            prev.TickerSymbol = curr.TickerSymbol
            AND prev.TradeDate < DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, curr.TradeDate))
            AND prev.TradeDate >= DATEADD(month, -2, DATEADD(day, 1, curr.TradeDate))
            AND prev.day_num = 1
WHERE 
    curr.day_num = 1
ORDER BY
      Year
    , Month
    , TickerSymbol;
```

Comment: This is great! However, as the "close" for each month, I'm looking to use the last stock closing price for that month rather than the average for that month. For example, if the closing prices in June 2010 for Apple stocks were 250 on the 20th of June and 225 on the 30th of June, (and the closing amount on May 31st was 300) I would want to list 225 as the current month closing and 300 as the previous month closing rather than using a monthly average.

Comment: @AmandaHansen, the correlated subquery will return the close price for the previous month, not the average.  It joins to the monthly average only to get the ticker and current month.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. Thanks! It is still returning numbers that are a little off.  For AAPL in Y 2000, M 1, the Current Close, is 25.8335. For AAPL in Y 2000, M 2, it shows the previous close is 25.41. I was hoping to have the 25.8335 pulled into the previous month close for the second month.

Comment: @AmandaHansen, I had an error in the date calculation such that it would return a earlier day than intended for months that had more days than the preceeding month.  I corrected the query so let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It is still pulling the wrong number on on the previous close column. (AAPL 2000, month 1 is 25.8335, and in month 2 it is showing the previous close price is 25.94.) I feel I'm still being a little unclear. I have gotten the 25.8335 number from my original query, but I am looking to only include the closing price on the last day of the month. For April 2010 (Y 2010, M 4), I want to show the Stock Closing price from the last day of the month, April 30th, 2010,  and the closing price from the last day of the previous month, March 31st, 2010. I am not looking to include averages.

Comment: @AmandaHansen, I thought you wanted the average of the current month and the close of the previous.  I changed my query to return the close of the current month too.  Securities that didn't trade during the prior month will be NULL but you can remove the lower TradeDate limit if you want to include the close from older months.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear about that in my question, but must have worded it incorrectly. This solves the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM (SELECT sd.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TickerSymbol, YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate)
                                ORDER BY TradeDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM StockData sd
      WHERE TradeDate >= '2000-01-01' AND ST_Close IS NOT NULL
     ) sd
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY TradeDate, TickerSymbol;
```

This gets all the information from the last record for each month.

ORDER BY YEAR(TradeDate), MONTH(TradeDate), TickerSymbol;

Comment: This is a great start, but I have to display the year, month, last ST_Close for that month and year, and the previous ST_Close for the month preceding the 'current' month. (If the ST_Close for AAPL in December 2011 (on the last day of the month) was 50, and the ST_Close for AAPL in November 2011 was 45 (again, on the last day of the month), I would need to List: 2011 (Year), 12 (Month), 50 (current close price),  and 45 (previous month close price). Sorry if I was being unclear.